# Replacing a light fixture

Tags: electrical, ground

How do I ground a new overhead light fixture?  I'm replacing a 2 wire fixture with no grounding wire with a new 3 wire fixture which includes a ground wire.  The new fixture is suspended not flush mounted, per the instructions.[image]

Comment: What is that photo showing us? There's obviously a ground wire present. Are you saying that there's no grounding conductor in the light box? What's the question?

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting a new question